# "msg": "failed to set permissions on the temporary files ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user

Tags: ansible, operating-system, aix

am running playbook an AIX managed host and when the task that requires root to become
and underpriviliged id for example testuser. I get the failed to become user because

permissions can't be set on file.

i have seen answers where its recommended to install setacl but that works for LINUX not AIX, any recommendations for AIX ?